# Updating data-value of input text box oninput not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set data-value of text box with the value of itself and the value of another input box. I have written simple javascript snippet to handle this at oninput attribute, but it is not updating the data-value attribute with the expected value.

```
<form onsubmit="return false" >
First name : <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" data-value="" oninput="txtFirstName.data-value = txtFirstName.value +' '+ txtLastName.value"/> <br><br>
Last name : <input type="text" name="txtLastName" oninput="txtFirstName.data-value = txtFirstName.value +' '+ txtLastName.value"/>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RXTV7/59/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `dataset.value` instead of `data-value`. For more info about [accessing data attribute value visit here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes#JavaScript_Access).

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  First name :
  <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" data-value="" oninput="txtFirstName.dataset.value = txtFirstName.value +' '+ txtLastName.value" />
  <br>
  <br>Last name :
  <input type="text" name="txtLastName" oninput="txtFirstName.dataset.value = txtFirstName.value +' '+ txtLastName.value" />
```